# How to run background timer with app closed playing audio samples in Swift

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer

I am making a drum machine app, which requires playing back short samples in a sequence. I would like to continue the sequence playing with the app closed.

I've followed the [standard process](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/creating_a_basic_video_player_ios_and_tvos/enabling_background_audio) for enabling background audio and data processing capabilities, but I need a suitable timer with at least second granularity that will trigger in the background.

What timer can I use with the app closed?

Here's some example code I want to continue playing:

**UPDATED WITH SOLUTION**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player: AVAudioPlayer? = nil
    var silence: AVAudioPlayer? = nil // SOLUTION

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let bass = Bundle.main.bundlePath + "/bd.mp3"
        let backing = Bundle.main.bundlePath + "/silence.mp3" // SOLUTION

        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: []) // SOLUTION
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true) // SOLUTION

            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: bass))
            silence = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: backing)) // SOLUTION
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(beat), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        silence?.numberOfLoops = -1 // Infinite // SOLUTION
        silence?.play() // SOLUTION
    }

    @objc func beat() {
        player?.play()
    }

}
```

Comment: Timers run in the background if started in foreground. Timer has subsecond granularity. You are the one triggering only every second. Unclear what issue you are having.

Comment: This timer doesn't run with the app closed, that's my question. I'll clarify.

Comment: I assure you that if the timer was running and audio was playing when you went into the background, they both continue in the background. It looks like the problem here is that you are trying to start a _new_ sound when you are already in the background. You can’t do that. Nothing to do with timers.

Comment: There are many similar dynamic drum machine / sequencer music apps that can play in the background @matt.

Comment: But they cannot produce new sounds. What you need is a single looping sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is to play a silent track on loop, which allows the timer to run in the background. My app then needs to stop the silent track to go into the background normally.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem here is that you are trying to start a *new* sound when you are already in the background. You can’t do that. That has nothing to do with timers. The timer runs but the call to `beat` fails and the app suspends.

Comment: This seems to be the issue. If I try a similar app (Korg Gadget) that supports background audio, it can seamlessly swap between foreground and background and has the red microphone icon top-left.